# How to configure proxy using Squid

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a connection and I want change the connection behavior of the process to connect through that proxy. I would also like it to use a new IP in the event that it detects that it has been throttled.

The new connection process that I want is :
connect from our server -> proxy -> required site
if we are throttled: establish new connection through proxy (need to confirm new IP is being allocated by the proxy)

Comment: better ask in http://serverfault.com

Comment: besides that it really should be asked on serverfault or perhaps superuser: which component is expected to get a new IP address (the proxy I assume) and how shall that happen ?

Comment: I have no idea about networking ... i want to connect through proxy to the server if the initial connection is throttled and want to use Squid for that as it is the available

Comment: I think i the solution on serverfault.com will work...thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this piece of code

```
import urllib2

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"---url of proxy goes here---"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen(---base-url goes here---).geturl()
```